# Split one big array into three

Tags: bash

I need to split one big array into three small ones. What I've tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a bigarray
bigarray=( 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 )
total=${#bigarray[@]}
let t1="$total / 3"
declare -a fstsmall
fstsmall=( "${bigarray[@]:0:$t1}" )
let t2="$total - $t1 - 1"
declare -a sndsmall
sndsmall=( "${bigarray[@]:$t1:$t1}" )
let t3="$t2 + 1"
let theend="$total - $t2"
echo $theendwq
trdsmall=( "${bigarray[@]:$t3:$theend}" )
echo "${fstsmall[@]}"
echo "${sndsmall[@]}"
echo "${trdsmall[@]}"
exit 0
```

This is fine, it returns me:

```
0 1 2 3
4 5 6 7
8 9 10 11
```

But if I add 12th element to big array, it broke into:

```
0 1 2 3
4 5 6 7
9 10 11 12
```

8th element is omitted. I suspect I need for loops for this, since number of elements is dynamic.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thanks for asking a detailed question!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for more on what to expect around here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let bash compute the size of the last slice for you.  I also switched your code to [`$(())` arithmetic expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/arith) since that's what I'm familiar with.

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a bigarray
bigarray=( 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12)    # also works without the 12
total=${#bigarray[@]}
slice_size=$(($total/3))    #Arithmetic expansion instead of "let"
declare -a fstsmall
fstsmall=( "${bigarray[@]:0:$slice_size}" )
#let t2="$total - $t1 - 1"    # Don't need this any more
declare -a sndsmall
sndsmall=( "${bigarray[@]:$slice_size:$slice_size}" )
#let t3="$t2 + 1"
#let theend="$total - $t2"
last_start=$(($slice_size * 2))
echo $last_start
trdsmall=( "${bigarray[@]:$last_start}" )   
    # Leaving off the :length gives you the rest of the array
echo "${fstsmall[@]}"
echo "${sndsmall[@]}"
echo "${trdsmall[@]}"
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what I've needed!